# indexOf("@") method in Java

Tags: java, android, twitter4j, indexoutofboundsexception, indexof

Why does this always return -1?
Does this have anything to do with '@' being the annotation symbol?

What can I do to search for the first occurrence of a substring starting with '@'?

```
 UserMentionEntity[] userMentionEntities = status.getUserMentionEntities();
    for (UserMentionEntity ume : userMentionEntities) {
        final String mention = ume.getText();
        int mentionStart = text.indexOf("@" + mention);
        int mentionEnd = mentionStart + mention.length();
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(COLOR)), mentionStart, mentionEnd + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Apparently, mentionStart is -1.
I am using twitter4j library.

Sample:

```
text: RT @Cornerstone_TMC Thank you @ukgdos at sa lahat ng nag-abang kanina kay @yengpluggedin! #SeenZoned @academyofrocksg… http://t.co/rsLqjlZJgg
mention: ukgdos
```

Comment: What is the value of `text`? What is the value of `mention`?

Comment: post a sample and expected result.

Comment: I am getting tweets from a public profile. Nothing special. Like this: "Wearing @snh_fashion flats.  http://fb.me/3CustlXWH"

Comment: @user3903214 Thank you. Now you have a proper question.

Comment: Now tell us where you are seeing `mentionStart` as `-`.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-1 ... 6) starts before 0

Comment: @user949 They have. See the sample.

Comment: Is there a space at the start of mention?  (Or is that in the print formatting)

Comment: nope. that is print formatting

Comment: text: blah... is not the raw String, cause it has colors.  Please show System.out.println(text).

Comment: System.out.println("text: " + text + " \nmention: " + mention);

Comment: Why is it red and blue?  I'm wondering if there are embedded control characters or similar.  Or is Stack Overflow adding helpful formatting?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis there formatted that one for me, so I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with my app.

```
    UserMentionEntity[] userMentionEntities = status.getUserMentionEntities();
    for (UserMentionEntity ume : userMentionEntities) {
        final String mention = ume.getText().toLowerCase();
        int mentionStart = text.toLowerCase().indexOf("@" + mention);
        int mentionEnd = mentionStart + mention.length();
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(COLOR)), mentionStart, mentionEnd + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

I noticed that Twitter allows you to change cases in the mentions.

`@yengPLUGGEDin` can be shown as `@yengpluggedin` so that `ume.getText()` in the code there returns the proper screenname while `text` contains the tweet text as it is.

I am not quite sure why it also failed on my sample input there. Maybe it didn't but failed on the next before the print was executed.

Answer (score 4):

No. Your String doesn't contain what you think it does,

```
String mention = "not";
String text = "I do @not think so.";
int mentionStart = text.indexOf("@" + mention); 
System.out.printf("%d%n", mentionStart);
```

Prints

```
5
```

**Edit**

Based on your now provided text and mention

```
String text = "RT @Cornerstone_TMC Thank you @ukgdos "
    + "at sa lahat ng nag-abang kanina kay @yengpluggedin! "
    + "#SeenZoned @academyofrocksg… http://t.co/rsLqjlZJgg";
String mention = "ukgdos";
int mentionStart = text.indexOf("@" + mention); 
System.out.printf("%d%n", mentionStart);
```

Prints

```
30
```

Comment: I am quite sure it does though. It prints afterwards. I will update my question

Comment: Can you put the *real* string in your post?

Comment: *"I am quite sure it does though ..."*.  We are VERY sure that it doesn't!

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. i thought it had something to do with the '@' symbol. i have fixed my problem.